# Getting SAX Parser attributes

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<Details><propname key="workorderid">799</propname>
```

How do i get 799 from workorderid useing SAXParing?
when i use this code i get "workorderid" but not the value of workorderid

```
if(localName.equals("propname")){
String workid = attributes.getValue("key");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(localName.equals("propname")){
```

//set one flag here and in endElement() get the value associated with your localname(propname)
    String workid = attributes.getValue("key");

I am providing you the code try to understand and customize in your way.

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private String item;
    private boolean inItem = false;

    private StringBuilder content;

    public ExampleHandler() {
        items = new Items();
        content = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, 
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        content = new StringBuilder();
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("propname")) {
            inItem = true;
        } else attributes.getValue("key");

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) 
            throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("propname")) {
            if(inItem) {
                item = (content.toString());
              }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) 
            throws SAXException {
        content.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // you can do something here for example send
        // the Channel object somewhere or whatever.
    }

}
```

May somewhere wrong i'm in hurry. If helps Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In `propname` the attribute `Key` having value `workorderid` which is correct.
You need to get the value propname.

```
  //Provide you tagname which is propname


 NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
            textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will hold the value of the node.

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch,start,length);
    }
```

In the event handler method, you need to get it like this:

```
if(qName.equals("propname")) {
   System.out.println(" node value " + tempVal); // node value
   String attr = attributes.getValue("key") ; // will return attribute value for the propname node.
}
```